# Apples for breakfast

Tags: eating-habits, breakfast

I am trying to loose weight and recently switched from Muesli to eating only apples for breakfast. It is faster, but is it also healthy?

Answer (score 1):

Apples are a perfectly healthy choice as they contain carbs but also plenty of vitamins.